# Error with NPM during the Developer Installation of ProcessMaker 4 (EBADENGINE)

Tags: node.js, npm, installation, package.json, processmaker

During the [Development installation](https://github.com/ProcessMaker/processmaker#development) of the NPM after introducing the `npm install` command on the Windows command prompt an error log appears

```
npm ERR! code EBADENGINE
npm ERR! engine Unsupported engine
npm ERR! engine Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @processmaker/processmaker@4.4.0-RC1
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @processmaker/processmaker@4.4.0-RC1
npm ERR! notsup Required: {"npm":"~8","node":">=16.18 >19"}
npm ERR! notsup Actual:   {"npm":"8.19.2","node":"v18.12.1"}
```

As you see I already modified the package.json to make it work with the current version of Node and NPM but for some reason it does not recognize it.

Im installing it on a Xampp in Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message mentioned, your node version is too high. The supported node versions for that project are [~16.18](https://github.com/ProcessMaker/processmaker/blob/f3d6b5671774cbc35682dce56b999954dff925ed/package.json#L131) meaning [16.18 + patches (16.18.x)](https://github.com/npm/node-semver/tree/dc0fe202faaf19a545ce5eeab3480be84180a082#tilde-ranges-123-12-1). You will need to downgrade to a 16.18.x version. I highly recommend setting up a node version manager; I'm not sure what people use on Windows these days, but I use [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/tree/7aee54b76cf75523b125a0d3c55d33f89c6fe8c1) for macOS.